# Create fastest possible localhost Ethereum test net

Tags: testnets, testing, ganache

Is there an Ethereum test blockchain (similar to Ganache) which prioritises calculating transactions and creating a local blockchain 'db' as quickly as possible?

Requirements:
 - Calculate transactions (i.e. smart contract logic) as fast as possible (c++ or rust environments for speed maybe?)
 - Write to local db (i.e. create the 'blockchain') quickly;
 - Retain ability to make RPC calls/tx's/queries to this local Ethereum 'blockchain' quickly;
 - Strip away all PoW & difficulty calculations (no consensus mechanisms - the localhost is the only source of truth);
 - Strip away all p2p communication;

^^^ all with the aim of having a super super fast test environment (albeit with some features removed).

Ganache is fairly quick, but has computational overhead to simulate some aspects of a blockchain that I don't need. I want to prioritise getting smart contract calculations completed and added to the db as quickly as possible. E.g. push a transaction to do very computationally heavy smart contract calculations as fast as possible, and then be able to query this 'blockchain' as fast as possible. Nothing more.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> You can use **`geth`** and set up private ethereum blockchain and get
>   fast transactions as you mentioned and make quick RPC calls.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rinkeby or gorlier poa testnet, if it’s not fast enough you can run your own testnet with small block time, say, 1-2 seconds